# Wher can I find a list of blueshifted regions in the Milky Way?

Tags: milky-way, redshift

It would be nice to get a relation between the blueshifted regions and the distance to earth. I'm searching especially for objects in other [galactic arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way#mediaviewer/File:Milky_Way_Arms.svg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a catalogue containing information about blue/red shift per region of the sky. You probably need a catalogue containing blue/red shifts per object and then calculate the average blue/red shift per region.
Most catalogues with blue/red shift are however targeted towards galaxies. They may also contain stars but you will have to filter the stars from the background galaxies. If I remember correctly, the [Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS)](http://www.sdss.org) contains a flag specifying whether an object is a galaxy or a star. So you might use the SDSS data to get a large set of stars with blue/red shift. This flag has been set automatically using pattern recognition. I do not know how good the classification was.

You can access the data at the [SDSS SkyServer](http://skyserver.sdss.org/dr12/en/home.aspx). There are a lot of objects in SDSS so you will need time to acquire the data and knowledge about SQL to query the database.

Even then, you still don't have information about the spiral arm in which the object is located although you might use a method such as was used by [Belokurov et al. (2006)](http://stacks.iop.org/1538-4357/642/i=2/a=L137) to detect the field of streams to separate the different spiral arms.